# Errorbars for unknown distributions

Tags: matlab, confidence-interval

I recently made a graph where I show the error bars for a certain number of "experiment". In another way, in my algorithm I'm minimizing the objective function so I would expect that increasing the sampling I'll get lower value of the objective function.

As you can see in the graph, the second value from the left, `2.5` on the x-axis, contain only 2.5% of the configurations, so we wouldn't expect it to perform as well as if we used 100% of the configurations.

I think that this is related to the **asymmetry** of the distributions. Is there any approach that can fix this problem - aka a method to compute CI for asymmetric unknown distributions?

[image]

This example should be useful to make this graph understandable!

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% EDIT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
i = number of replicates (with different seed so different sampling every replicate)
z = objective function value
n = number of configurations
j = 1...n
```

Example: `n=1000`, `i=100`

1. Step 1. Analyze all the `1000` configurations and compute the minimum
   of `z_j`. Store it and replicate for `i`. Then compute mu and sigma of
   those `z_i`
2. Step 2. Analyze `50%` of the initial `1000` configuration and
   compute the minimum of `z_j`. Store it and replicate for i. Then
   compute mu and sigma of those `z_i`
3. Step 3. Analyze `10%` of the initial `1000`
4. Step 4. Analyze `5%` of the initial `1000`
5. Step 5. Analyze `2.5%` of the initial `1000`

So we will have `mu_100`, `mu_50`, `mu_10`, `mu_5`, `mu_2.5` and `mu_1` and `sigma_100`, `sigma_50`,...

Now I'm able to make those error bars like `mu_100 + - 2 * sigma_100`....

Comment: What do you mean by "The second value from the left (Sampling of 97.5%) seems perform a better results of sampling 0%"? (In simple Italian if you want, I can translate for others to see)

Comment: And why do you expect that with big sampling you'll get higher value of objective function? Does the function explicitly depend on sample size?

Comment: You might be better off asking this at stats.stackexchange, as the issue here lies not really within matlab, but apparently within the proper way to estimate uncertainties

Comment: @LuisMendo I mean that the value at `2.5` has 97.5% less configuration to sort than the one at `100`. If you see the lower limit of the errorbar goes lower than the `100` value. So, in simple words, the graph is saying that enumerate less value is better than evaluate'em all. (I have make 100 repetitions to estimate mu and sigma). And, yes, the function depend because is a discrete enumeration process, so the configurations that i analyze in `2.5` are in `100` too.

Comment: @sebastian I think you are right, but maybe some admin can move my question to stats. I'll wait before cross posting.

Comment: hm, weird, I could vote to move the question to some other sites, but stats.stackexchange is not among them °°

Comment: @sebastian LoL, I think I'll make some cross posting then!